Failed to custom Response type in Express.js using TypeScript
I am trying to custom my own Response interface to extends some methods instead of using default Response type of Express.js but I am getting an TypeScript error:

The last overload gave the following error. Argument of type '(req:
Request, res: CustomResponse, next: NextFunction) => void' is not
assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'.ts(2769)

I have researched many different ways to solve this issue such as: declare namespace but it didn't really work for me so I decided to choose another way which is custom my interface that extending from Response interface of Express.js. Below is my code:
import { Response } from 'express';

interface CustomResponse extends Response {
   myMethod: () => void;
}

...

app.use((req: Request, res: CustomResponse, next: NextFunction) => {  // <=== error causing from CustomResponse
   res.myMethod();
});


You can find an example for adding custom property to Express request object using declaration merging here

If this example doesn't work for, can you please share how you've tried to use it in your code?

You can Explicitly Type Cast Like this
  app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {  
       const customResponse = res as CustomResponse;
       customResponse.myMethod();
       //customResponse.send();
    });


huge thanks, this should be last way.
